# Mongoose populate with filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My schema:

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    Category: String,
    Subcategory: String,
    Name: String,
    Offers: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: "Offer" }]
})

const OfferSchema = new Schema({
    Quantity: Number,
    Images: [String],
    Price: Number,
    Size: String,
    Color: String
})
```

I am doing query for products with filter offers with limit and skip. I tried this:

```
const products = await ProductSchema.find({ ...someFilter }).populate({
    path: "Offers",
    match: {
        Quantity: { $gt: 2 },
        Images: { $exists: true, $ne: [] }
    }
}).skip(skip).limit(limit)
```

And I want to get only documents where length of offers is > 0. But I get documents with empty Offers. If I filter like this:

```
products.filter(item => item.Offers.length > 0)
```

My pagination will break. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just require the `Offers` field to not be empty like so:

```
const products = await ProductSchema.find(
    {
        ...someFilter,
        "Offers.0": {$exists: true}
    }
).populate({
    path: "Offers",
    match: {
        Quantity: {$gt: 2},
        Images: {$exists: true, $ne: []}
    }
}).skip(skip).limit(limit)
```

Comment: It's close, but Images of Offers could be empty array, so i do not need them.

Comment: Then i recommend you either create a new field on the documents like `image_count` and match on `image_count > 0`. The only way to do this in 1 db command would be to use `aggregate` which is really bad performance wise for padgination as you'll have to lookup on the entire collection before the skip and limit can be used.

Comment: So i think, i have to add image_count to Offers? But it will be the same thing.